# How can I remove items from dictionary using lambda expression?

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda

I am using simple predicate to determine if the key should be removed.
For example if the dictionary is construct like `Dictionary<int, int>`, how should I remove all the entries with negative values?

I prefer to use the same dictionary, not to create new one.

I don't have performance issues.

Is there a way to do it, without using LINQ, but using Lambda expressions?

I didn't want solutions in LINQ because no one is using them in my project, didn't want to be the first. But because I saw the LINQ solutions look better, I will use them.

Comment: negative data in key or value? or both?

Comment: I think you can't use lambda expressions without linq in this case

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to create a *new* dictionary, if that's okay for you:

```
var newDictionary = oldDictionary.Where(pair => pair.Value >= 0)
                                 .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key,
                                               pair => pair.Value);
```

If you *have* to mutate the existing dictionary (e.g. because several other objects have reference to the same dictionary) you'd need to build a list of keys to remove, then remove them afterwards:

```
var toRemove = dictionary.Where(pair => pair.Value < 0)
                         .Select(pair => pair.Key)
                         .ToList();

foreach (var key in toRemove)
{
    dictionary.Remove(key);
}
```

EDIT: I've just noticed the first sentence: "I am not into LINQ solutions". If that means you don't want to *use* a LINQ solution, here's the by-hand version:

```
List<int> toRemove = new List<int>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> pair in dictionary)
{
    if (pair.Value < 0)
    {
        toRemove.Add(pair.Key);
    }
}

foreach (var key in toRemove)
{
    dictionary.Remove(key);
}
```

... but if you *can* use LINQ, I'd encourage you do. My second solution is equivalent to the "by-hand" version, but more readable IMO.

Comment: Which reference should I add to support 'Where' key word?

Comment: @Delashmate: Add a reference to `System.Core` and add `using System.Linq;`. This is assuming you're using .NET 3.5 or higher.

Comment: @Delashmate: I've only just seen the bit saying you're "not into LINQ solutions" - do you mean you don't have experience of them, or you don't *want* a LINQ solution?

Comment: @Jon, I didn't want solutions in LINQ because no one is using them iside my project, didn't want to be the first..

Comment: @Delashmate: If everyone in your project takes that attitude, you'll *never* use LINQ. Aren't the LINQ solutions here clearly simpler to understand, and more declarative? I *strongly* suggest that you embrace LINQ - it's a fabulous technology. At *least* discuss it with your teammates.

Comment: @Jon, I embraced your advice :)

Comment: @Delashmate - good decision :)  I started with LINQ around 3 months ago and have never looked back - it's pretty awesome!

Answer (score 13):

By merely using lambda expression:

```
foreach (var i in myDict.Where(d => (d.Value  < 0 || d.key <0)).ToList() ) 
{
  myDict.Remove(i.Key);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this break because you're modifying the collection while iterating over it?

Comment: The `ToList()` method creates a clone so you're iterating over a clone and removing from the original dictionary

Comment: Oh yeah! I guess it would break without the `ToList()` :)

Answer (score 5):

```
var toRemove = dict.Keys.Where(predicate).ToArray();
foreach (var key in toRemove) {
    dict.Remove(key);
}
```

Comment: Note that ToList is generally more efficient than ToArray. Unless you *need* an array, ToList is preferred IMO.

Comment: @Jon, not that I'm doubting you but why would that be ? Isn't an array a more lightweight structure than a list ?

Comment: @mikel: An array has to be *exactly* the right size. The way you typically build up a "large" collection is by doubling a buffer size each time you need to. That works well for a list where you can just use the oversized buffer afterwards - but if you need an array afterwards, you will often need to copy all the data in the buffer to a *new* array of exactly the right size. See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/02/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-24-toarray.aspx for roughly what ToArray has to do.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with .Net Core 3.0 is actually safe to remove dictionary items during enumeration. So the simplest solution would be:

```
foreach (var kv in dictionary)
    if (kv.Value < 0)
        dictionary.Remove(kv.Key);
```

Look at remarks at documentation of the [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove) method:

> .NET Core 3.0+ only: this mutating method may be safely called without invalidating active enumerators on the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` instance. This does not imply thread safety.

And this is how this feature became a thing: [Allow Dictionary<K,V>.Remove during enumeration](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26314).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove the items from that dictionary, or are you happy to use a new dictionary without those items included?

```
var d = new Dictionary<int,int>();
var newDict = d.Where(entry => entry.Value >= 0).ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, entry => entry.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest one:

```
Dictionary<long, long> dict...
Dictionary<long, long> result = dict.Were(x => x.Value >= 0).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Or just loop over all in 'for' in reverse order and remove invalid ones.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you add

```
namespace MMExtensions
{
    public static class DictionaryExtensions
    {
        public delegate bool Predicate<TKey, TValue>(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> d);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        public static void Filter<TKey, TValue>(
            this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> hashtable, Predicate<TKey, TValue> p)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> value in hashtable.ToList().Where(value => !p(value)))
                hashtable.Remove(value.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

And you had some dataset as dictionary:

```
    Dictionary<string, int> d =
            new Dictionary<string, int> {{"v", -3}, {"val1", 1}, {"val2", 2}};
```

Then you could use:

```
    d.Filter(delegate(KeyValuePair<string, int> kv) { return kv.Value >= 0; });
    d.Filter(kv => kv.Value >= 0);// or as lambda
```

Comment: I don't think you need `MethodImplOptions.Synchronized` here

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you are not into Linq, but I could not contain myself with the following solution, plus it is still useful if you read the title of your question.  This is probably the most elegant solution to your problem:

```
dictionary.Where(pair => pair.Value < 0)
          .Select(pair => { 
              dictionary.Remove(pair.Key);
              return pair.Key;
          });
```

Comment: rather than `Select` use `Any` with `return false` (or `All` with `return true`, more natural)